# webpack how to run babel-loader on files outside the project directory?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I am using webpack2, babel-loader

```
import something from '../../customPackageOutsideProjectDirectory';
```

the above line of code gives the following error:

```
    Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
at throwError (/Users/sahilsharma/workspace/projectTry/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2823:21)
```

The error is probably because of lack of .babelrc file outside the project directory.
How to get this package loaded correctly from outside ?

Answer (score -1):

The `.babelrc` file isn't necessary if you config Babel in webpack using the options:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader